# Format x axis of Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have a Google Line Chart which I feed some data like in this example:

```
['Time', 'Temperature'],
['00:00', 5, ],
['01:00', 12, ],
['02:00', 14, ],
['03:00', 18, ],
['04:00', 17, ],
['04:20', 17, ],
['04:30', 18, ],
['04:40', 22, ],
['05:00', 24, ],
['06:00', 20, ],
['07:00', 17, ],
['08:00', 17, ],
['09:00', 16, ],
['10:00', 17, ],
['11:00', 16, ],
['12:00', 15, ]
```

I would like to have the x-axis display only the hours of a day, in 24h mode.

There can be one or several values per hour, but the range of the x-axis should be fixed and linear (0-23).

Take a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1b3hd0ya/10/

How can that be done?

**Edit:**

Actually the problem can be solved by using proper Date objects in the x-axis, and formatting them with `HH:mm`.

Answer (score 0):

It would work like this, which means I have to change the date format.

https://jsfiddle.net/1b3hd0ya/12/

```
  google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['line', 'corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Time', 'Temperature'],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 5],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 12],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0), 14],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0), 18],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0), 17],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 4, 20, 0), 17],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 4, 30, 0), 18],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 4, 40, 0), 22],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0), 24],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0), 20],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 7, 0, 0), 17],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0), 17],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0), 16],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 10, 0, 0), 17],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 11, 0, 0), 16],
          [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0), 15]
      ]);

      new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {
          "height": 500,
          "curveType": "function",
          "lineWidth": 2,
          "pointSize": 2,
          "vAxes": {
              "0": {
                  "title": "°C",
                  "format": "#,##00.00 °C"
              }
          },
          "hAxes": {
              "0": {
                  "title": "Time",
                  "format": 'HH:mm'
              }
          },
          "series": {
              "0": {
                  "targetAxisIndex": 0
              }
          }
      });
  };
```

Comment: you could also use data type --> `'timeofday'` -- see [working with timeofday](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday) -- values in first column would need to look like --> `[0, 0, 0]`, `[0, 30, 0]`, `[1, 0, 0]`, `[1, 30, 0]`...

Comment: Thanks. I would also need to have days and possbily months. Sadly a good old unix timestamp does not seem to be possible as far as I know as of now.

Comment: I tried also the date string representation ["Date(2017, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)", 12, ] which does not work neither ... https://jsfiddle.net/1b3hd0ya/13/

Comment: the above date string will only work when creating the DataTable directly from json, using the [format found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), not when using `arrayToDataTable` (although not seen in the example provided)...